# vscode open all files in all subdirectories with matching extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are extensions to open all search results [1].

There are extensions to open all files in a directory [2].

Is there an extension or a way to open all the `.py` files in all sub-directories?

References

1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-search-open-all-results
2. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ko-dev.vscode-open-files-in-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems there is one extension called Open Multiple Files.

It uses glob e.g. `**/*.py` and then opens all the matching files.

Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-open-multiple-files